# My files are gone after I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: files, filesystem, helpfile

I was using Ubuntu 16.04 then I downloaded Ubuntu 17.10, put it on a bootable flash drive and installed it. During the installation the system asked me if I want to Delete everything and reinstall the system or to keep all files possible and just update the system. I chose to keep all the files and update.

Until there it was OK, but now it's already installed and I no longer have access to my files. I looked at the hard drive and it's 63% full which means that my files still are there. How can I get access to those files from my current system? or How can I get those files without an external hard drive?

I tried everything, but I end up losing all my files, I'm glad everyone who help me in the way they could.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Run `ls -la /home`, check if there are old files in there. If not, post the output of `lsblk` and `ls -la /home`

Comment: I take two screenshot it's better to view take a look https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B003ymjiZUOnUHg1NWY2bF8wYlk

Answer (score 1):

your new username (and consequently home dir) is called `gianlucca`.

your old username and home dir (from 2015) was called `gian`. your files are probably there.

but i also see that some home dirs are encrypted. if it was the old one and you didn't save the recovery key, you lost it all.

Comment: Yeah I have the key, but don't know how to proceed

Comment: follow those steps. but keep in mind the recovery key is NOT your old password. https://askubuntu.com/questions/238047/how-do-i-mount-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-another-ubuntu-machine

Answer (score 0):

There are two folders in /home location which are dated Sep-17 and Jun-17. Check if they have the data you need. Else, include results of `sudo du -h -d 1 /home 2>/dev/null` and `sudo du -h -d 1 / 2>/dev/null`. This would help determine where the 63% disk is getting consumed.

Edit: The folder location `/home/.ecryptfs` is showing as 294GBs. Use `cd /home/.ecryptfs` to access it. Use `ls -la` to check the content there. If it is encrypted you may not access it and would need to follow this: [Access encrypted drive on separate partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580057/access-encrypted-drive-on-separate-partition)

Comment: gianlucca@gianlucca-OptiPlex-3020:~$ sudo du -h -d 1 /home 2>/dev/null
[sudo] password for gianlucca: 
603M /home/gianlucca
4.0K /home/gian
294G /home/.ecryptfs
575M /home/novo_usuario
295G /home
(gianlucca@gianlucca-OptiPlex-3020:~$ sudo du -h -d 1 / 2>/dev/null
9.9M /run
12M /sbin
3.4G /usr
1.1G /opt
4.0K /dev
12M /bin
116K /tmp
295G /home
0 /sys
12K /media
3.0M /root
486M /boot
635M /var
4.0K /lib64
4.0K /srv
474M /lib
16K /lost+found
13M /etc
4.0K /mnt
0 /proc
4.0K /snap
4.0K /cdrom
303G /

Comment: I'm still not able to upload photos here, for a better view you can see the screenshot of the terminal I uploaded to my google drive >>> https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B003ymjiZUOnUHg1NWY2bF8wYlk

Comment: Check this out `294G /home/.ecryptfs`. This where it should be. You can press `Ctrl+H` to view hidden files from `File Manager`.

Comment: 294  /home/ .ecryptsf = command not found, the Ctrl+H show me a lost+found folder that requires password but it's empty and in properties it says unreadable.

Comment: I meant that the folder location `/home/.ecryptfs` is showing as 294GBs. Use `cd /home/.ecryptfs` to access it. Use `ls -la` to check the content there. If it is encrypted you may not access it and would need to follow this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/580057/access-encrypted-drive-on-separate-partition

Comment: Yes, it is encrypted and I can't mount the folder, but it's there with 315giga

Comment: I have a similar issue after a normal update. All my desktop, documents and home file are "gone"( but I found that the disk is full anyway but the part is not mounted) and with a search a found a file that was under "download" and now is under etc/NetworkManager/system_connections. Any ideas how to rescue those?